# JetBrains GoLand permanently loosing version control state: need manual refresh on any change

Tags: javascript, version-control, jetbrains-ide, goland

Every now and than the IDEA based GoLand JetBrains IDE refuses to work along side with Node.js (react/redux/JS) based applications.

The problem looks like this:

1. When you change something, the file is marked orange which kind of suggests, that the file is in undefined state (as far as I remember).
   [image]
2. The file is not listed as changed in the Version Control, you need to hit refresh:
   [image]
3. After refresh, the file is in defined state again and:
   [image]
   the file is also listed as blue (changed)
   [image]

But what is the reason for this issue, it should not need manual refresh all the time!

Comment: sometimes even refresh does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file or folder it resides in is added to Version Control | Ignored Files, as the olive color the file had initially indicates ignore.

It is not possible to ignore tracked files though, so it behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: THANKS MAN!!! It was indeed the case, I don't know how it happened to be like that, but when I found the "Configure Ignored Files" Panel, it listed the current project dir. Once removed the behavior seams be normal again. You saved my day!